# How can I get the content of a file input with pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I modified a file input button (basically it is hidden and something else is rendered on top of it), and I want to get the 'meta' content of it after one or more files are uploaded - in the default input file button, there is a text that gives the user information about the submitted files (one file uploaded/ 10 files uploaded, and so on, depending on the browser).

I did this via jQuery, with the code below, but unfortunately I can not use jQuery on the website because there is another js library that influences many plugins and behaviours (masonry).

```
<script>
$("#upload-form-file-button").change(function () {
var fileName = $(this).val().replace('C:\\fakepath\\', '');
if (this.files.length == 1)
    $("#upload-info").text(this.files.length + " image selected");
else
    $("#upload-info").text(this.files.length + " images selected");
});
</script>
```

How can I do this in pure javascript, so that I don't have to change the js library?

Thank you.
Tibi

Comment: Seeing as jQuery is written in pure JavaScript, I would bet money it is incredibly possible.

Comment: You want to read the file or the file name?

Comment: Note that it's also completely possible for you to use the javascript in your question alongside masonry without conflict.

Comment: Btw, Masonry can be used with jQuery, so you shouldn't end up with issues because of that

Comment: @LGSon I want to get the number of files uploaded via the file selector. I am not sure if the conflict is from Masonry, but a slider that relies on js fails to work propery if I load the jQuery library

Comment: So instead of trying to figure out why it fails to work properly you're going to just back down and give up? For all we know the fact that it uses jQuery may have nothing to do with why it stops working properly. the jQuery in your question shouldn't be conflicting with masonry at all, it's more likely that you incorrectly included a second copy of jQuery.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, you are right. I will also look into that in the future, but now, I was mostly curious how can I properly write it in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translated your jQuery to vanilla JS:

```
document.getElementById("upload-form-file-button").onchange = function () {
  var fileName = this.value.replace('C:\\fakepath\\', '');
  var uploadInfo = document.getElementById('upload-info');
  if (this.files.length == 1)
    uploadInfo.innerText = this.files.length + " image selected";
  else
    uploadInfo.innerText = this.files.length + " images selected";
};
```

Additionally, if you have a conflict with jQuery's `$` variable, you can always load jQuery with [noConflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/).

Comment: No problem. If you need help translating jQuery into vanilla JS on your own, [use this resource](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/).